# Is it "backyard" or "back yard"?

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference between them? I saw yesterday "back yard" when I thought you could only write "backyard".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Supplement to the Oxford English Dictionary has *'Backyard'*, *Back Yard'* and *'Back-yard'*.  I'd suggest you take your pick, with none being more correct than any other, although to use *'Back-yard'* might suggest a certain pedantry or old-fashioned approach by the writer or in the writing, given that common usage has made the hyphen unnecessary in explaining the meaning.  *'Back Yard'* and *'Back-Yard'* have a longer history (from the OED):

> back-yard back yard, back-yard
>   [back- A. 5.]
>   A yard or enclosure at the back of a house. Also fig.
>
> *1659 in Suffolk (Mass., U.S.A.) Deeds (1885) III. §246 A **back yard** lying on the north side of the sajd dwelling house. 1679 Bedloe Popish Plot Ep. a, Creeping into **back-yards**, and firing stacks of Bavins. 1771 Pennant Tour in Scotland 1769 125 Land sufficient to build a house on, with gardens and back-yard. 1860 O. W. Holmes Prof. Breakf.-t. x. 311 A stone with a whitish band crossing it, belonging to the pavement of the back-yard. 1882 C. Pebody Eng. Journalism xxiii. 186 The crowing of a cock in the back-yard of a suburban villa. 1920 J. Mander Story of N.Z. River i. iv. 64 When you..have seen the **backyard** side of people..you don't get upset by trifles. 1933 Bulletin (Sydney) 1 Feb. 11 Nine Sydney he-men out of ten get sun-tanned by lying in the back yard. Ibid. 13 Sept. 10/2 She worked a backyard farmlet in one of the outer suburbs. 1950 N.Z. Jrnl. Agric. Aug. 143/1 Few backyard henhouses appear to be planned for the number of birds they ultimately hold. 1962 Listener 11 Jan. 51/2 Inside the area which a substantial power regards as its own backyard, the writ of the United Nations does not run.*

Why an area adjacent to a dwelling (or indeed an area used to enclose stock such as sheep, cattle, etc) is called a yard is an interesting question that leads on from this.  It is not because the space is measured in *'yards'*.  Essentially *'yard'* as in the enclosed space is related to the word *'garden'* as the OED explains:

> yard ▪ I.yard, n.1
>   (jɑːd)
>   Forms: 1 ᵹeard, 4–5 ȝerd(e, 4–6 ȝard(e, yerde, 4–8 yerd, 4–9 yaird, (4 ȝherd, 5 ȝeard, ȝord, yorde, 6 ȝharde, 7 yearde, 8 Sc. yeard), 5–6 ȝaird, 6–7 yarde, 3– yard.
>   [OE. ᵹeard str. masc. fence, dwelling, house, region = OS. gard enclosure, field, dwelling, MDu., Du. gaard garden, OHG. gart circle, ring, ON. garðr garth, (Sw. gård yard, Da. gard yard, farm), Goth. gards house, with corresp. wk. forms OFris. garda garden, OS. gardo, OHG. garto (MHG. garte, G. garten) garden, Goth. garda enclosure, stall. (OE. ᵹeard is the second element of middanᵹeard middenerd, ortᵹeard orchard, w{iacu}nᵹeard winyard.)
>
> The ulterior relations of these words are uncertain. Close affinity of sense is exhibited by the words derived from the Teut. root gerd-: gard-: gurd-, represented by gird v.1 (OE. gyrdan, OHG. gurten, ON. gyrða) and girth n.1 (ON. gjǫrð, Goth. gairda), and those derived from an Indo-European root ghort-, viz. Gr. χόρτος farm-yard, feeding-place, food, fodder, L. hortus garden, co-hors enclosure, yard, pen for cattle and poultry, cohort, court, OIr. gort cornfield; but there are phonological difficulties in the way of equating both groups of words. (OSl. gradŭ enclosure, town, Russ. grad, gorod town, as in Petrograd, Novgorod, Lith. gàrdas hurdle, fold, are prob. borrowed from Teutonic.)
>   The general signification of the word is ‘enclosure’, the particular character of which is usually to be inferred from the context; the simple word is thus often felt to be short for a specific compound of it (see references in the various senses).]
>
> 1. a. A comparatively small uncultivated area attached to a house or other building or enclosed by it; esp. such an area surrounded by walls or buildings within the precincts of a house, castle, inn, etc. Cf. back-yard, castle yard, chapel yard, courtyard, inn-yard, palace yard, stable-yard. In OE. used in sing. and pl. = dwelling, house, home, the ‘courts of heaven’; also, region, tract (cf. middanᵹeard middenerd).
>
> *Beowulf 2459 Nis þær hearpan sweᵹ, ᵹomen in ᵹeardum. a 1000 Cædmon's Gen. 740 (Gr.) Wit..forleton on heofonrice heahᵹetimbro, godlice ᵹeardas. a 1000 Guthlac 763 (Gr.) Swa soðfæstra sawla motun in ecne ᵹeard up ᵹestiᵹan rodera rice. c 1375 Sc. Leg. Saints xviii. (Egipciane) 571 To þe tempil men cane draw; & of It til in þe ȝarde I wes cummyne, I ne spard. c 1400 St. Alexius (Laud 108) 302 Alex..Is dweld in his fader ȝerd As a pore man. 1524 Test. Ebor. (Surtees) VI. 10 A litile howse with a yerde. 1562 J. Heywood Prov. & Epigr. (1867) 100, I kepe doggis..in my yarde. 1565 in Hay Fleming Reform. Scotl. (1910) 613 Part of ane yard within the abbay place of Sanctandrois. a 1657 Sir J. Balfour Ann. Scot. Hist. Wks. 1825 II. 71 He was brought vpone a scaffold in the parliament yaird. 1711 Addison Spect. No. 121 ⁋1 As I was walking..in the great Yard that belongs to my Friend's Country-House...*

However, whether there is a connection between the word *'yard'* which defines length, and which originally referred to a rod, stake or spear, and the sense of the word meaning enclosed space is a much deeper question.  One might suspect that it may have something to do with spaces being enclosed by stakes or palisades, or follow some path from the root of the word *'guard'*, but this would be idle speculation.